# Computer restarts during render

Tags: rendering

I have a big problem: my computer restarts automatically during a render. I haven't received any error messages, but nonetheless something must be wrong as blender shuts down every time I try to render a scene. 
I have a good gaming laptop and I render on my GPU. There is still lots of space on my memory card. Can someone please tell me what to do in order to prevent my computer from shutting down! 
I've included screenshots to show my render settings.

Many thanks in advance, 
Maura

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to update your graphics driver.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the issue: my graphics driver was already up to date.

Comment: When it's not a driver issue I would do a stress test on the GPU with a benchmark software to see if it also crashes. If it does, the following to causes seem the most likely: Either you GPU has a defect or your PSU doesn't provide enough power under peak load.

Comment: what can I do o increase the amount of power under peak load?

Comment: Buy a PSU with a higher wattage. Before you do that though, check what components are in your computer and how much wattage your current PSU supports, since it's not clear cut if that's the cause. There are online calculators that help estimate, e.g. (not affiliated) https://www.bequiet.com/en/psucalculator